# what does the lock id mean in java thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading

I usually observed the lock id (as following) in the thread dump:

```
"Thread-pool-Bill" - Thread t@42
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    - locked <79f0aad8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
```

In `locked <79f0aad8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)`, what does `79f0aad8` mean? It doesn't seem to be an object address nor object id cause I couldn't find it from heap dump. So what it is?

Answer (score 1):

its address of internal lock construct(monitor object) for hotspot JVM.

```css
code for your reference
    oop o = _locked_monitors->at(i);
    instanceKlass* ik = instanceKlass::cast(o->klass());
    st->print_cr("\t- locked <" INTPTR_FORMAT "> (a %s)", (address)o, ik->external_name());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it an opaque identifier. The key is that other pieces of code may be waiting on that particular lock, which will also show up in the thread dump. So you can use it to match up waits and locks between threads. It may also show up in the JVMs thread dump deadlock detection outputs - but I'm not sure.

The entry appears in the stack trace from either a synchronised method, or explicit synchronised block, and is related to the object synchronized on.

Comment: If I take two thread dumps at separate points in time on the same JVM, can I compare these identifiers?  The two stack traces I'm looking at in different dumps suggests the locked object is the same one (the method has not returned and not called again) but the ID seems to have changed, e.g. if it's the memory address as @Jamsheed comments below, then that could correspond to a garbage collection moving the locked object.

Comment: @GraemeMoss my understanding is that you can't rely on the locations of the objects to be the same between runs - so using the lock id to identify the objects wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Its the hashcode/id of the object on which the Thread owns the lock.  Since your thread is RUNNABLE so some other thread may or may not be waiting on it. If another thread is waiting for this lock then your Thread dump would have another entry somewhere else showing a BLOCKED or WAITING Thread which is waiting for lock on the same id i.e 79f0aad8

But since you say you cannot find this String (79f0aad8) anywhere else in your file so either:

- you have multiple thread dump files or
- the thread Thread t@42 wasn't blocking any other thread when the thread dump was taken.